# Html binary image to pdf in java

Tags: java, html, pdf

I have a html file which has image in binary form.
I want to convert that to pdf using java.
Can anyone please help me with this?
And the Html file contains Base64 image file

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
        Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf"));
            // step 3
            document.open();
            document.newPage();
            document.add(new Chunk(""));
            // step 4
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("/home/farheen/workspace/html.to.pdf/test.html"));    
            //step 5
             document.close();

            System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
        }catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I have edited my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itext](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/)

With this example code from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html)

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ImageExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("Image.pdf"));
        document.open();

        Image image1 = Image.getInstance("watermark.png");
        document.add(image1);


            String imageUrl = "http://jenkov.com/images/" +
            "20081123-20081123-3E1W7902-small-portrait.jpg";

            Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
        document.add(image2);

        document.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```